# Using StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, encode

The latest release of Json.NET (4.5.11) contains StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii, which escapes all non ASCII chars.  But, I can't figure out where to pass it as a parameter.

If I try:
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii});`

then I get compile errors:
`'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings' does not contain a definition for 'StringEscapeHandling'`

Comment: "I get compile errors" is far too vague. Give details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](http://www.thinkbase.net/main/raw-attachment/blog/thinkbase-2012/11/24/Json.NET-Documentation-20121124-james.newtonking.com.7z), this property is only available on JsonWriter and its inheritors.

Comment: I'm new to Json.NET - could you show how to convert the above into JsonWriter?

Answer (score 3):

On more recent versions of Newtonsoft.Json this is available on `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.  Pass a `JsonSerializerSettings` instance where [`StringEscapeHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_StringEscapeHandling.htm) is `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii`.