# How to use Json.NET StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii

Tags: c#, .net, json, escaping, json.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii with Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095247/using-stringescapehandling-escapenonascii-with-json-net)

The latest release of Json.NET (4.5.11) contains `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii`, which escapes all non ASCII chars. But, I can't figure out how to use it.  The docs don't seem to have any examples that I can find (only a release note announcing it).

Could someone show an example of serializing an object into a JSON string, using `EscapeNonAscii`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this example can help

```
string obj = "abcn\n\rüö&/<>";
Console.WriteLine(Serialize(obj, StringEscapeHandling.Default));
Console.WriteLine(Serialize(obj, StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml));
Console.WriteLine(Serialize(obj, StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii));


public static string Serialize(object o,StringEscapeHandling stringEscapeHandling)
{
    StringWriter wr = new StringWriter();
    var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(wr);
    jsonWriter.StringEscapeHandling = stringEscapeHandling;
    new JsonSerializer().Serialize(jsonWriter,o);
    return wr.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Just hit the same problem. Is there any way to do this using standard JsonConvert.Serialize object to preserve other settings?

Comment: @chester89 yes. It's an option on the Settings object    **settings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml** that you can just pass to JsonConvert().

Comment: @chester89 [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/03807ce2a60d5d1c895ff867565db4dbc8cfb569/SendGrid/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/Mail.cs#L350) is an example