# escape accented chars on utf-8 json

Tags: c#, json, character-encoding, json.net

the code below produce this output:

```
{"x": "Art. 120 - Incapacità di intendere o di volere"}
```

i need to change to this, i suppose i've to change something on encoding but i don't know what:

```
{"x": "Art. 120 - Incapacit\u00e0 di intendere o di volere"}
```

code:

```
string label = "Art. 120 - Incapacità di intendere o di volere";
JObject j = new JObject();
j.Add(new JProperty("x", label));
string s = j.ToString();
Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
string filename = @"c:\temp\test.json";
using (FileStream oFileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
    using (StreamWriter oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(oFileStream, encoding))
    {
        oStreamWriter.Write(j.ToString());
        oStreamWriter.Flush();
        oStreamWriter.Close();
    }
    oFileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: 1) A json string containing accented characters is perfectly fine when you're using UTF-8 encoding. No need for escaping. 2) Which serializer are you using? Newtonsoft json.net? 3) [`StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106894/how-to-use-json-net-stringescapehandling-escapenonascii)

Comment: i've to follow that strange requirment, i'm using Newtonsoft.Json. if there's not another way i'll do a string replace.

Comment: You can use `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like others said, you want to use StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string label = "Art. 120 - Incapacità di intendere o di volere";
        JObject j = new JObject();
        j.Add(new JProperty("x", label));
        string s = j.ToString();

        var sr = new StringWriter();
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sr) {
            StringEscapeHandling =  StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii
        };
        new JsonSerializer().Serialize(jsonWriter, j);

        Console.Out.WriteLine(sr.ToString());
    }
}
```

outputs

```
{"x":"Art. 120 - Incapacit\u00e0 di intendere o di volere"}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/s5VppR