# .NET Core 6- HtmlEncode response string through global declaration

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-6.0, html-encode

While returning `Json` Response from .NET Core 6 Web APIs, I want to encode all strings with `WebUtility.HtmlEncode`. As of now, I am writing this line for each string and I just came across this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117929/3234665.

Is there anyway we can declare this at some central/ global level (i.e. Attribute, Program.cs etc?) to reduce repetitive lines everywhere?

Comment: All Web Api end points you want to return HTML Encoded strings? If so, you can create a custom middleware provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

For globally add the custom `ContractResolver`,you need add the configuration in your Program.cs like below :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

//add this service to container...
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
    Formatting= Formatting.Indented,
    DefaultValueHandling= DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,  //add this
};
```

Comment: Do I need to add `JsonConvert` lines directly in `Program.cs` file?

Comment: Hi, do you mean you also don't want to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` every time? You can only globally setting the serialization settings. Serialize or not only can be controlled by JsonConvert.

Comment: You are right. I am returning a response directly. I have below code in `Program.cs`.
`services.AddControllers()
 .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull);`

Comment: Hi, DefaultIgnoreCondition cannot work fine by `AddJsonOptions`  in your code, you need set like what my answer did by using the `DefaultValueHandling`. PLs check.

Comment: Still do I need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` after that line?

Comment: Yes. of course you need. As my first comment said, you can only globally set the serialization settings, but cannot control the serialization itself.