# ascii is not allowed in JSON string parameter in asp.net API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to send a JSON string from an ajax call to an ASP.NET api.
The JSON string arrives but it is truncated at an ascii code.

So how can I allow ascii code in my parameter string?

Here is the related code:

```
function sendBewerkVacature(id) {

    var velden = document.getElementsByClassName("veld");
    var veldenArray = "{'" + velden[0].name + "' : '" + velden[0].value+"'";

    for (var i = 1; i < velden.length; i++) {
        veldenArray = veldenArray + ", '" + velden[i].name + "' : '" + velden[i].value+"'";
    }
    veldenArray = veldenArray + "}";
    var JSONVelden = JSON.stringify({ "velden": veldenArray });
    console.log(JSONVelden);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:26454/api/Vacatures/PostEditVacature?id=" + id + "&velden=" + JSONVelden,
        type: "POST",
        statusCode: {
            200: function (data) {
                alert("Geslaagd!");
            }
        }
        })
}


public HttpResponseMessage PostEditVacature(int id, string velden)
{
    db.vacatures.Find(id);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    vacatures vacature = (vacatures)serializer.DeserializeObject(velden);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

The string that is sent looks like this:

```
object a:{"velden":"{'FunctieTitel' : 'Natuurkunde', 'school_naam' : 'undefined', 'vak_naam' : 'Natuurkunde', 'aantal_uren' : '18-25', 'datum_ingang' : '16-2-2011', 'omschrijving' : '<p>Voor de afdeling havo/vwo klas 2 en 3 zijn wij op zoek naar een docent(e) Natuurkunde 2e graads voor 18 tot 25 lesuren per week.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Locatie: Koninginnelaan te Vlaardingen</p><p>Klassen: leerjaar 2 en 3 havo/vwo</p><p>Salaris: inschaling in LB, arbeidsvoorwaarden conform CAO Voortgezet Onderwijs.</p><p>Ingangsdatum: 01-08-2011, tijdelijke aanstelling met uitzicht op een vaste aanstelling.</p>'}"}
```

but in the controller it looks something like this:

```
{"velden":"{'FunctieTitel' : 'Natuurkunde', 'school_naam' : 'undefined', 'vak_naam' : 'Natuurkunde', 'aantal_uren' : '18-25', 'datum_ingang' : '16-2-2011', 'omschrijving' : '<p>Voor de afdeling havo/vwo klas 2 en 3 zijn wij op zoek naar een docent(e) Natuurkunde 2e graads voor 18 tot 25 lesuren per week.</p><p>}
```

Comment: How exactly are you viewing the strings you've shown here?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095247/using-stringescapehandling-escapenonascii-with-json-net

Comment: I place a break point right under : public HttpResponseMessage PostEditVacature(int id, string velden)
        {

Comment: What code did you use and what was the result? ` &#38;` is not a valid  ASCII code for JSON - JSON doesn't have ASCII codes. JSON only allows Unicode in the form `\u1234`. Post the code you used, the original text and the result, so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Please put all of this into the *question* rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're sending the json in a query string.

Your querystring looks something like:

```
?id=1234&velden={'vacancy_name': 'clown', 'vacancy_description':'juggle &#38; be funny'}
```

So now your querystring contains an unexpected `&`, signifying the end of one querystring parameter and the start of the next.

You need to

```
encodeURIComponent(JSONVelden)
```

before you add it to the querystring.

Even better, learn how to post JSON rather than sending it in query string parameters.

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. Thanks a lot!